# Self keyword usage in python? Detailed Explanation would be possible as if you're explaining a kid

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, object, self

I know that self keyword in python is a reference to the instance of that particular class, but how can one create an object within the same class? can someone please explain this concept to me in detail?

Comment: you mean a generic object instance? or an object instance of the same class within itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all that you should be aware of the differences between class, object and instance.

The class is basically the code definition of an entity.

An object or instance, usually mean the same exact thing: a running unique specific entity loaded in memory.

I personally make a distinction between the two, but this is probably just my opinion:

- I use `object` in a phase when I am reading the code functionally and I want to say something like `this is the object kind returned by this method`.
- I use `instance` when referring to the actual object running in memory.

===

Now in a python class, any member can be defined as an object, for example:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_member = MyOtherClass()
```

Please note that the class itself inherit from `object`, which is the base class (or the mother of all the python classes).

```py
In [1]: object??
Init signature: object()
Docstring:
The base class of the class hierarchy.

When called, it accepts no arguments and returns a new featureless
instance that has no instance attributes and cannot be given any.
Type:           type
Subclasses:     type, weakref, weakcallableproxy, weakproxy, int, bytearray, bytes, list, NoneType, NotImplementedType, ...
```

===

If you meant instead, "How can I add an instance of the same class as a member of the class?", the following could be a way to do it:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.another_instance = None

    def set_instance(self, instance):
        if not isinstance(instance, MyClass):
            raise TypeError("Wrong instance type!")
        self.another_instance = instance

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
a.set_instance(b)
```

Here I will also share with you the wrong approach:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.another_instance = MyClass()

a = MyClass()
```

This code will result in a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. This because if you think about it, each class instance will try to create a new instance, which will try to create a new instance, which will try... and so on.

====

This could be another way to do it, but I wouldn't suggest it unless for a very specific and particular case (maybe something related to chained objects, but there's surely a better way to manage this.)

```py
In [1]: class MyClass(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, has_link=False):
   ...:         if has_link:
   ...:             self.another_instance = MyClass(has_link=False)
   ...:

In [2]: a = MyClass(has_link=True)

In [3]: a.another_instance
Out[3]: <__main__.MyClass at 0x110fe00d0>
```